# Django foreign key insertion

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm migrating my Python to a REST API, I'm using Django framework 1.8.
I followed the tutorial and one of my requests is to insert an Object (Server) which depends on few fk. In my Python App I normally have 3 queries to insert the records, use **RETURNING id** to store the Ids of the FKs and finally 1 query to insert my Server object. How can I achieve this in Django?
These are my models and serializer:

**serializers.py**

```
#Server Serializer
class ServerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Server
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'discovered', 'status', 'serialnumber', 'hostname', 'description', 'created')
```

**models.py**

```
class Server(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='server')
    discovered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    serialnumber = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    
    fk_server_model = models.ForeignKey('ServerModel', db_column='fk_server_model')
    fk_licensing = models.ForeignKey(Licensing, db_column='fk_licensing', blank=True, null=True)
    fk_network_services = models.ForeignKey(NetworkServices, db_column='fk_network_services', blank=True, null=True)
    fk_network_interfaces = models.ForeignKey(NetworkInterfaces, db_column='fk_network_interfaces', blank=True, null=True)
    fk_server_credentials = models.ForeignKey('ServerCredentials', db_column='fk_server_credentials', blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Server, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'server'
```